# Calling Akka.Net Actor from function and get back Acknowledgement

Tags: c#, .net-core, akka.net

1. I have an actor system with a supervisor actor implemented in the domain that is being called from outside the domain
2. The function invoking the supervisor actor has to wait till the response is received from supervisor in order to take the next step
3. Using Tell this won't be possible.  Using Ask, how can the supervisor actor send the message back to the calling function?

I have used "Ask" but since there is no actor invoking the supervisor actor, nothing is returned

```
var result = await supervisorActor.Ask(msg);
```

Inside the supervisor actor to return back ack (this is not working)

```
private Unit Handle(Unit msg)
        => msg;
```

Comment: I think you might want to look at `Inbox`: https://getakka.net/articles/actors/inbox.html

Comment: Thank you very much.  "Inbox" works for me.  As documented in the link above  "Ask" does not receive multiple replies.

Comment: @mclark1129 you should post that as an answer!

Comment: @GautamTGoudar I added this comment as an answer if you wouldn't mind accepting it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to https://getakka.net/articles/actors/inbox.html, you should be able to use the `Inbox` class to interact with actors from outside the actor system.

```
var target = system.ActorOf(Props.Empty);
var inbox = Inbox.Create(system);

inbox.Send(target, "hello");

try
{
    inbox.Receive(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).Equals("world");
}
catch (TimeoutException)
{
    // timeout
}
```